# ASP Razor Web Pages - Form Submit is Moving My Data

Tags: html, forms, razor, asp.net-webpages

When I submit my `Login` email (aka username), I want to keep it in my `Login` form.

When I submit my `Register` email (aka username), I want to keep it in my `Register` form.

What is happening is: when I submit my `Login` form, it writes the email (aka username) to the `Register` form. Please see image for what is happening.

[image]

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Login";
    var username = "";
    var password = "";
    var errorMessage = "";

    var confirmPassword = "";
    var regMsg = "";
    var confToken = "";
    var emailBody = "";
    var minPass = 2;
    var maxPass = 5;


    if (!IsPost) {
        if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {errorMessage = String.Format("You are already logged in. (Username: {0})", WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);}
    }

    if(WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated){
        errorMessage = String.Format("You are already logged in. (Username: {0})", WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
    }

    if(IsPost){
        // Login Form
        if (Request.Form["loginSub"] != null){
            regMsg = "";
            username = Request["username"];
            password = Request["password"];
            if(WebSecurity.Login(username,password,true)){
                Response.Redirect("~/Profile");
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = "Invalid Username or Password. Please try again.";
            }
        }
        // Register Form
        if (Request.Form["registerSub"] != null){
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            errorMessage = "";  
            username = Request["username"];
            password = Request["password"];
            confirmPassword = Request["confirmPassword"];
            try {
                var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(username);
            } catch {
                regMsg += "<br>Invalid email format.";
            }
            if (password != confirmPassword) {regMsg += "</br>Passwords don't match.";}
            if (WebSecurity.UserExists(username)) {regMsg += String.Format("</br>User '{0}' already exists.", username);}
            if (password.Length < minPass || password.Length > maxPass) {regMsg += "</br>Password doesn't meet length requirement.";}
            if (regMsg == "") {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username,password,null,false); //Switch with "true" token
                regMsg = String.Format("{0} created.", username);
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Email verification sent! Please check your email to activate your account.');</script>");
                //Response.Write("<script>location.href = 'Default.cshtml';</script>");
            }
        }
    }
}
<style>header {visibility: hidden;}</style>
 <body>
    <h1>MySite</h1>
    <p>
        @if(errorMessage != ""){<span>@Html.Raw(errorMessage)</span>}
        @if(regMsg != ""){<span>@Html.Raw(regMsg)</span>}
    </p>
    <fieldset class="fs100">
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <form method="post" name="login">
            @if(WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated){
                <p>You are currently logged in as @WebSecurity.CurrentUserName.
                    <a href="@Href("~/Logout")">Log out</a>
                </p>
            }
            <p>
                <label for="username">Email Address:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password:</label><br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
            </p>   
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="loginSub" value="Submit" />
            </p>        
            <p><a href="@Href("~/Register")">Forgot Password?</a></p>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>
        <form method="post" name="register">
            <p>
                <label for="username">Email Address:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value='@Request["username"]' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password @minPass-@maxPass Characters:</label><br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
            </p>   
            <p>
                <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label><br/>
                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" value="" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="registerSub" value="Register" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: That's exactly what you told it to do (`value='@Request["username"]'`)

Comment: Easy Fix! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is echoing the value from the request in the second form.

If you don't want it to do that, change your code to do something else.

You may want to change each form to have unique field names.